# create time of tables retrieving in qt

Tags: mysql, qt

```
QSqlQuery query;
QString querytime="SELECT CREATE_TIME FROM information_schema.tables WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA ='test_150' AND TABLE_NAME ='"+table+"'";
if(query.exec(querytime)){
   cout<<"TIME STAMP>>>>>"<<query.value(0).toString().toStdString()<<endl;
}
```

I have used above code for retrieving the creation time of tables from MYSQL in QT. But it is not working. I tried this query in MYSQL frontend and it is working properly there. What is the error in this code?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
QSqlQuery query("SELECT CREATE_TIME FROM information_schema.tables WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA ='test_150' AND TABLE_NAME ='"+table+"'");
while(query.next()){
    cout<<"TIME STAMP>>>>>"<< query.value(0).toTime().toString().toStdString()<<endl;
}
```

I'm not sure what is `CREATE_TIME type`, so I used `toTime()` but it may be of other type so if it doesn't work try `toDateTime()` and `toDate()`.

Comment: it also not giving answer..:(

Comment: then try cout<<"TIME STAMP>>>>>"<<query.value(0).toTime().toString().toStdString()<<endl;